# Java/Gradle error with versions or something

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew, minecraft-forge

So, I have several Gradle projects that I am working on at the moment and when I do **any** command in the correct folder starting with `./gradlew` it returns this error:

```html
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.9.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

What is even going on?
Here is some other stuff that **might** be useful:
Im on mac
my java version is OpenJDK 11.0.9.1
i **don't** have Gradle installed on my system, I have it in the project directory. (e.g. I use ./gradlew not gradlew)

Any help would be appreciated, So thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: I do **NOT** have 2 gradle installations... I have already stated this but apparently some1 just came in and said it was the same question...

I still need this to be fixedddddddd

Comment: This question is not a dupe, **please vote "reopen"**.